# Alterar carácter da placa dos veículos - Padrão Mercosul

Tags: oracle11g

No banco de dados Oracle, tenho a tabela (Tab_PlaVei) com o campo string (PlaVei), formato **UUU9999**. Preciso ajustar este campo para o novo padrão de placas do Mercosul, formato **UUU9U99**.
Gostaria de executar uma comando `SQL` para corrigir todas as placas que já foram cadastradas no formato **UUU9999** alterando para o novo formato **UUU9U99**, ou seja, alterar o 2º caractere numérico ou o 5º da string, conforme a tabela padrão de placa Mercosul, conforme abaixo:
Placa antiga    Placa Mercosul
    0   A
    1   B
    2   C
    3   D
    4   E
    5   F
    6   G
    7   H
    8   I
    9   J

Vocês podem me ajudar a fazer o comando correto para resolver essa situação?

Comment: Dê uma lida nas funções [CharIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp) e [Substring()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp)

Comment: Mas afinal, qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: mysql, oracle ou sql server?

Comment: vou utilizar no oracle, mas a sugestão pode ser em qualquer um, se preferir oracle

Comment: Importante definir com clareza o DB usado, pois a solução varia conforme o engine. Aí pode aproveitar para postar o que tentou, na forma de [mcve], descrevendo a dificuldade. Se quer simplesmente saber como inserir um caractere dentro de uma string, pode simplificar bem a pergunta retirando todas as informações supérfluas da razão de estar fazendo isso, tornando possíveis soluções compatíveis com o modelo do site (pergunta sobre problema objetivo, respostas úteis para uma gama grande de usuários, o que fica comprometido pela especificidade das placas).

Comment: Fiz a edição da pergunta com mais detalhes, obrigado pelo comentário!

Answer (score 3):

Eis sugestão para SQL Server.

```
-- código #1 v2
SELECT Placa, 
       -- método 1
       substring (Placa, 1, 4) +
       char ((65 + cast (substring (Placa, 5, 1) as int))) +
       substring (Placa, 6, 2) as [Placa 1],
       -- método 2
       stuff (Placa, 5, 1, 
              char ((65 + cast (substring(Placa, 5, 1) as int)))) as [Placa 2]
  from tbPlaca;
```

O código acima considera que a placa está declarada como texto (char(7), por exemplo) e que possui sempre 7 caracteres.

---

Para o Oracle Database, acho que fica o seguinte:

```
-- código #2
SELECT Placa, 
       -- método 1
       substr (Placa, 1, 4) ||
       chr ((65 + cast (substr (Placa, 5, 1) as integer))) ||
       substr (Placa, 6, 2) as [Placa 1],
       -- método 2
       stuff (Placa, 5, 1, 
              chr ((65 + cast (substr(Placa, 5, 1) as integer)))) as [Placa 2]
  from tbPlaca;
```

Comment: Eu não vou escrever uma resposta porque usando `STUFF` é a melhor solução. Também da para usar o `Regexp_Replace` :  `REGEXP_REPLACE(Placa, '[[:digit:]]{1}', substr (Placa, 1, 4) + '\1' + substr (Placa, 6, 2) )`

Comment: Augusto, acrescentei mais informações!